# Convert Magento 2 equivalent for Mage::helper

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2

I need a help to convert below code to Magento 2.

```
class Grid extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid
{
    protected function _prepareColumns() {

    $this->addColumn('entity_id', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('ID'),
            'width'     => '50px',
            'index'     => 'mageuserid',
            'type'  => 'number',
            'filter_index' => 'main_table.mageuserid'
        ));
    }
}
```

Specifically `Mage::helper('customer')->__('ID')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `__('ID')`. This is because `Mage::helper('customer')->__('ID')` used for translation only. They are equal.

Comment: So, will it become 'header'    => __('ID') ?

Comment: @AbhishekAnand yes, it is.

Comment: Thanks for that, could you also help me converting this $groups=Mage::getModel('mppartnergroup/mppartnergroup')->addFieldToFilter('status',array('eq'=>1))

Comment: @AbhishekAnand you should open new question, I will take a look and answer you. Because, it's more complicated. I need to clarify some info.

Comment: you are right, created new thread for that http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/153675/need-magento-2-equivalent-for-magegetmodel