# Need Magento 2 equivalent for Model Filter

Tags: magento2, model, filter

I need a help to porting below code to Magento 2.

```
$groups=Mage::getModel('mppartnergroup/mppartnergroup')
                    ->addFieldToFilter('status',array('eq'=>1))
```

Comment: How about your issue?

Comment: Got it resolved, had to port old model code from plugin first before doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you have already the Model class: `\Vendor\Module\Model\Mppartnergroup`

`Mage::getModel('mppartnergroup/mppartnergroup')` can be equal to `\Vendor\Module\Model\Mppartnergroup`. Inject the model factory as dependency.

```
protected $modelFactory;

public function __construct(
    ......
    \Vendor\Module\Model\MppartnergroupFactory $modelFactory

) {
   ......   
   $this->modelFactory = $modelFactory;
}
```

Now, we can filter:

```
$groups= $this->modelFactory->create()
                    ->addFieldToFilter('status',array('eq'=>1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to inject the model into your constructor class and then you can call its methods:

```
protected $_mppartnergroup;

public function __construct(
    ..
    \vendorName\vendor\Model\Mppartnergroup $mppartnergroup
) {
    ..
    $this->_mppartnergroup = $mppartnergroup;
}
```

At this time you can call its methods:

```
$this->_mppartnergroup->addFieldToFilter('status',array('eq'=>1));
```

Comment: you need to use factories for creating transient objects. Look at magento documentation http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html#injectable-and-newable-objects